# How Much Pressure Drop across the fuel filter is normal / acceptable?

Tags: fuel-filter, fuel-pressure

I was just curious how much of a pressure drop is usually normal across a fuel filter on a typical consumer passenger car?

Comment: I have nothing to back it up, but I would expect no pressure drop at all.  Have you seen otherwise or are you just asking?

Comment: @OP You need to be more specific. What kind of car is this?

Comment: I would think that any resistance to a fluid flow would cause a pressure drop across it, just like a resistance in an electrical circuit will cause a voltage drop across it.  I don't know how much it would be for a clean fuel filter but it should be minimal.

Comment: Doesn't it have to provide enough fuel pressure on the output side to be greater than what is needed at the fuel pressure regulator? If it drops below that point, you'd start seeing fuel starvation, lean burn, and pinging ... at least in a fuel injected vehicle.

Comment: Fuel pressure is not the issue. The amount of fuel flow is the critical issue. Pressure assumes the fuel is no longer flowing whereas pressure has to do with pump pressure and no flow. Theoretically, fuel will flow through a filter faster than the pump can supply it. When it slows that flow, pressure is not affected until the "flow" slows to a point that the pressure is affected.

Comment: Why do you always have to ask hard questions?

Comment: @Ppoggio what can I say in general interesting questions are hard to answer.

Comment: @X-tech2 - If the filter interrupts the flow, pressure on the inlet side of the filter will be higher than the output side. If something downstream of the filter is causing more of a flow interruption, you'd never know the difference at the filter. I think your reasoning may be right, but the way you are saying it seems all out of whack.

Comment: The pressure drop would be a function of flow rate, I can't answer your question specifically but the pressure drop should be zero when the flow is zero, and increase as flow increases. I'd speculate that it wouldn't ever be more than a couple of psi

Comment: @paulster2 - Sorry if I was unclear.  All filters can handle more flow than should ever occur.  The amount of possible drop in pressure has to be so small it probably cannot be measured with normal pressure equipment. All fuel injected vehicles now have a return, so fuel is constantly flowing, pressure is always maintained. Therefore, fuel pressure is maintained on both sides of the filter. So, the question was, what is the pressure drop, and the answer is that it is so small it probably cannot be measured easily.

Comment: @Simon Moss - When there is such a large amount of filter material, fuel will flow with very little resistance, therefore little to no pressure change. The amount of fuel flowing through a 1/4" line can easily flow through the filter without issue. Until it gets stopped up with dirt of course.

Comment: @X-tech2 so it seems like you've got an answer?

Answer (score 3):

This will all depend on the type of fuel pump that your vehicle uses. The stronger the pump, the larger the pressure difference it can manage. If you wanted to calculate a theoretical limit, I guess you could estimate it by calculating the fluid power based on the flow rate your engine requires and the pressure upstream of the fuel filter:

```
Power = Pressure * volumetric flow rate
```

Make sure you're careful with the units in your equation, but this will tell you the maximum pressure you can have upstream of your fuel filter before your fuel pump craps out. As an example, if you have a 0.05 watt fuel pump and your engine uses 0.1 gal/hr of fuel, then:

```
Pressure = Power / volumetric flow rate 
         = 0.05 watt / 0.1 gal/hr 
         = (0.05 watt * 0.73756 ft-lb/s * 1/watt) * (1 hr / 0.1 gal * 3600 sec/hr * 1 gal / 0.133681 ft^3 * 1 ft^2 / 144 in^2)
         = 68.9 PSI
```

I dunno if 0.05 Watts is typical for a fuel pump. I do think 0.1 gal/hr is realistic for fuel rate at idle. So, based on this analysis, our pump can handle 68 PSI. If the fuel line pressure is 60 PSI, then that means we can handle an 8 PSI increase in pressure due to a restriction in the fuel filter.

I should note that this analysis is very very basic, and does not take into account pump efficiency or pressure drop due to the pipe length and other obstructions.

Comment: I marked it up because the information is interesting but I don't think it actually answers the question.

Comment: you know, either the original question changed or I misread it. I thought they were asking the max pressure drop that is allowable.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to buy a new fuel filter, and measure after the old filter, and before and after the new filter.  I let it idle two minutes before taking each reading.  After the old filter, which had been in there for ages, it read 35 psi.  Before and after the new filter were both also 35 psi, although the needle on the prefilter reading was jittering a little bit.  I think when I installed the new filter a little bit of filter material might have gotten blown out and stuck in the fuel regulator or return line ( or something ) cause I was getting 43 psi for a little while right after installing the new filter.

Anyways, this seems to validate what JPhil1618 and X-tech2 were saying, that there should be zero measurable pressure drop across the filter.

While this doesn't answer the general question, it does give one point of empirical data.

Answer (score 0):

It is about ~1,5 to max. 3 kPA (0,2-0,45 PSI) for a new filter.

Answer (score -1):

A fuel pump demand about 1 amp for each 10 psi of pressure.

A typical Fuel pump works at 50 psi, this Is about 5 amperes. The normal working voltaje on a running motor Is about 14 volts.

Power(watt) = Volt * Amp = 14 * 5 = 70 watt.

Not 0,05 watt.

Thanks for all the information bring here !!